# Валидатор выдает ошибку:"Этот документ не прошёл тест"

Tags: html, css, валидация

Валидатор при проверке страницы выдаёт ошибку, которая гласит, что документ страницы не прошёл тест? Где я ошибся? Спасибо!
https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/check?ucn_uri=shveypokrov.ru&ucn_lang=ru&ucn_task=conformance#

Comment: а разве там не написаны ошибки?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Написаны, но беспокоит то, что вот эта ошибка вылазит. Мало ли, может быть из-за неё не все ошибку будут показаны.

Comment: ну так непонятно в чем проблема. если ошибки написаны, то надо  исправить. в чем тогда вопрос немного непонятно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский попытаюсь объяснить.Там самым первым пунктом отмечена ошибка чтения css-документа. То есть, он не может его прочитать полностью/частичнно. А если не может прочитать, то где гарантия, что ошибки точны/определены в полной мере.Я понял вот так) Если не прав, то поправьте, пожалуйста)

Comment: если использовать `/css/main.css` или `css/main.css` (не знаю структуры папок) - что-то изменится?  зачем абсолютные url кстати?

Comment: Сейчас ошибок чтения я там не вижу

Comment: Спасибо, я уже исправил. Указал абсолютный путь "http://shveypokrov.ru/css/main.css" и всё заработало. А почему удалили ответ человека, который подсказал мне это?

Comment: Он сам удалил. Но вообще абсолютный путь указывать - это неверно

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а почему неправильно? Какие-то последствия? А как правильно?

Comment: Относительные пути обычно пишут..... почему неправильно? ну например поменяется домен. придется искать где были ссылки и исправлять домен.. с первого раза как правило все упоминания не находятся.. даже через поиск с регуляркой....... далее был http стал https - опять исправлять и т.д.

Comment: @Quick Brown Fox я по ошибке удалил))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас сейчас вот что прописано:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
```

А нужно, что-то вроде:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://shveypokrov.ru/css/main.css">
```

Comment: абсолютные пути? серьезно?

Comment: ......O_O......